# Is it possible to setup an ssh with multiple folders without using mount bind?

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, symbolic-link, openssh

I have important files in two different locations, one mounted at `/home` and another at `/mnt/my_storage`. I'd like to get the folders of `/mnt/storage` and with `/home/Downloads` to be accessible over ssh. I currently have it setup using multiple (too many) mount binds.  I don't like the idea of having a drive mounted at different locations. Is it possible in any other way? (Maybe symlinks?)
Edit : I've chrooted the user, if that's important.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the complete file system hierarchy over `ssh` (I assume you mean `scp`) as long as the SSH user has the file system permissions to do so.

If you mount via `sshfs` or `gvfs` and you don't give a base folder, your home directory will be used, but if you do give a base folder (`/mnt`) you can directly access that location.

**EDIT**

With the additional information of the `chroot` jail: This is **designed** to make all parts of the file system tree, that is not mounted inside the `chroot` jail completly invisible. This implies, that symlinks pointing out of the jail are broken (and must be so if the `chroot` works as expected).

So basically, if you do use `chroot` you must mount inside the jail (possibly via `bind`). If you are prepared to sacrifice the jail, you can use them.

N.B. The value of `chroot` is often overestimated: If you have a shell, it's trivial to bypass it, and if you don't have a shell the only protection it offers is against too lose file permissions.

Comment: I'm using opeenssh. The user has permission to the drives but I cannot follow symlinks. To mention, I have chrooted the user to a directory as I don't want them to access all the files, only the media files are shared. How to do that using something other than mount bind?

Comment: If you `chroot` you lock the user out of most of the file system tree - and of course you break symlinks. You should also mention this in the Question.